# Error Deploying Release Pipeline Windows 2016 deprecated - Azure Devops

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I got this error message:

This is a scheduled windows-2016 brownout. The windows-2016 environment is deprecated and will be removed on April 1st, 2022. For more details, see https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/5238

Took me forever to figure out it was and I hope this helps anyone facing same issue:

[image]

The release pipeline agent needs changing from 2016 to 2019 or whatever you build on as long as its > 2016

Answer (score 2):

The release pipeline agent needs changing from 2016 to 2019 or whatever you build on as long as its > 2016

Answer (score 1):

What I figured out is that, at some point, any agent that's using the 2016 configuration could be in Azure Pipeline or Azure Release. So what I did was the following:

1. Checked in my project config (`web.config`/`appsettings`) if I was referring to it somehow.
2. Checked my pipeline configuration (`azure-pipelines.yml`). It was one of the issues. So instead of having:

   ```
   pool:
     vmImage: 'windows-latest'
   ```

   It was changed for the following

   ```
   pool:
     vmImage: 'windows-2019'
   ```

   > ***Note:*** Since the project was using .NET Framework MVC 5, it was pointing to v4.5.1, so it was changed to 4.8 first. Before I changed to 4.8, this was the error that I got:

   [image: Error shown in azure]
3. After getting the message above, the only thing that wasn't considered was the release configuration, so that was it! Go to *Releases* > *Edit* > *Run* on *Agent*. In here, the *Agent Specification* label was pointing to `vs2017-win2016`. So I changed it to `windows-2019` and it did the trick!

Also this post helped. In case you're using some soon-to-be-deprecated Windows Hosted config: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/5403